# React - Is there is a difference between TransitionGroup / ReactCSSTransitionGroup / CSSTransitionGroup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-transition-group

So I cannot figure out why people like to call the `React Transition Functions` in the different ways by

> TransitionGroup:
>   `import TransitionGroup from 'react-transition-group/TransitionGroup'`
>
> ReactCSSTransitionGroup `import ReactCSSTransitionGroup from 'react-transition-group'`
>
> CSSTransitionGroup `import CSSTransitionGroup from 'react-transition-group/CSSTransitionGroup'`

So, the question is there some differenses (performance, functionality) between these invokes or it just on the mind of the developer - how to call the Transition from `react-transition-group`...

P.S.
I do not find the answer on this question in the web.

I'll be pleased for any help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [index.js](https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group/blob/master/src/index.js) the following are the same:

```
import { TransitionGroup } from 'react-transition-group'
import TransitionGroup from 'react-transition-group/TransitionGroup'
```

The since CSSTransition exports a default class the following is misleading:

```
import TransitionGroup from 'react-transition-group/CSSTransition'
import AnyThing from 'react-transition-group/CSSTransition'
```

Comment: Thank you! But the question is about another - is there some differenses in the functionality of these Transition functions? )

Comment: @SviatKuzhelev: As shown in the `index.js` link, they all refer to the exact same object. There's no functional difference between which one you use.

Comment: @JoeClay in the `index.js` it says next: `import CSSTransition from './CSSTransition';
import ReplaceTransition from './ReplaceTransition';
import TransitionGroup from './TransitionGroup';
import Transition from './Transition';` . I my opinion these four classes are linked from different files... Or I'm wrong?

Comment: They are linked to different classes.

Comment: https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group/blob/master/src/TransitionGroup.js

Comment: https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group/blob/master/src/CSSTransition.js

Comment: @SviatKuzhelev maybe the confusion is that above you say CSSTransitionGroup but that’s not correct. It is CSSTransition. The transition group class allows you to group multiple transitions (ie CSSTransition)

Comment: So, as you say `They are linked to different classes`, in that way we can suppouse, that if they are all linked to different classes, they also have different methods/functions? @RyanSchumacher

Comment: https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group/blob/master/src/CSSTransition.js#L99-L115

Comment: https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group/blob/master/src/TransitionGroup.js#L62-L81